# Facebook app how to hide/show some divs to admin and normal users through javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I'm working in Facebook app using Facebook SDK.

In **Javascript**,

I want to show some divs when the person who is viewing my page is admin and I want to hide some divs when that person viewing my page is not an admin, just the viewer.

I tried out,

**Script:**

```
   <script>
FB.api({ method: 'pages.isAdmin', page_id: '189986511194609' }, function (response) {
    if (response) {
        alert('the user is an admin');

    } else {
        alert('the user is not an admin');
         document.getElementById("txt1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("submit").style.display = "none";
    }
});
   </script>
```

but it didn't work for me. The user who is not an admin viewed the page, still the elements are not hidden.

Could someone have idea how to implement that?